# Can't insert object into object array in Mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, push

I've been trying to get certain elements into this code. (Please ignore the silly dummy data)

```
{
"Order_Number": "1",
"Status": "Pending",
"Customer":{
    "First_Name": "Juan",
    "Second_Name": "De La Cruz",
    "Email": "juandelacruz@gmail.com",
    "contact": "0923275937"
           },
"Shipping_Address": "291,Ominous Building, Quezon City, Philippines",
"Billing_Address": "IOU, Iowa, USA",
"Weight": "200 lbs.",
"Description": "Joots",
"Tracking Information": {
    "Tracking Number": "000000001",
    "Shipping History": {
        "Shipping Transactions": [
            {
                "Date Received": "10/1/2013",
                "Date Released": "10/10/2013",
                "Source": "Center of the earth",
                "Control Number": "100010001"
            },
            {
                "Date Received": "10/2/2013",
                "Date Released": "10/12/2013",
                "Source": "Center of Venus",
                "Control Number": "100010002"
            },
            {
                "Date Received": "10/3/2013",
                "Date Released": "10/13/2013",
                "Source": "San Francisco",
                "Control Number": "100010003"
            }
        ]
    }
}
}
```

Now , I've been trying to get these elements into "Shipping Transactions".

```
{

        "Date Received": "10/2/2013",
        "Date Released": "10/11/2013",
        "Source": "Center of Mars",
        "Control Number": "100010005"
}
```

I've tried doing push , but it doesn't even seem to add itself to the array.

```
{$push:{"Tracking Information":{"Shipping History":{"Shipping Transactions":
   [{"Date Received": "10/4/2013",
    "Date Released": "10/11/2013",
    "Source": "Center of Mars",
    "Control Number": "100010005"}]
 }
```

Might this code have a flaw or am I doing something wrong ? I'm only using MongoDb's web shell btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
{
  $push:{"Tracking Information.Shipping History.Shipping Transactions": {"Date Received": "10/4/2013",
    "Date Released": "10/11/2013",
    "Source": "Center of Mars",
    "Control Number": "100010005"}}
}
```

It's called [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation). Really useful.